# JS Elegent way to split a relative URLmultiple times to get only a part of the URL?

Tags: javascript

So I got this function where I retrieve a URL from SP2010. Which gives me a relative URL that does me no good.

e.g.

> 8;#reports/125/ReportList/closedTasks.rdl

I split this multiple times to retrieve the part I need. 
 For one var I need the reports/125/ReportList/closedTasks.rdl
So the part after the #. And only split method required to do so.

But for an other var I only need the file name without the extension. 
So only closedTasks.

Because of this I need the do multiple split method like below.

Is there a more elegant way to do so?

```
var relName = ($(this).attr("ows_FileRef")).split("#")[1];
var relNameSub = relName.split("/")[3];
var name = relNameSub.split(".")[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.slice()` and `.lastIndexOf()`

```js
var url = "8;#reports/125/ReportList/closedTasks.rdl";

var hash = url.slice(3); // slice the first 3 characters

var fileName = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.lastIndexOf(".")); // slice following last "/" ending at `"."`

console.log(hash, fileName);
```

Comment: @Emocuc _"please note that using slice and indexOf is not a very efficient as perhttps://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substr-vs-substring-vs-split-vs-regexp/2 you really want to go with Regular Expression on this.."_ ? The link results list `RegExp` as the slowest. Are you sure that you linked to the correct jsperf relevant to the suggestion to use `RegExp`? What is the purpose of `opt = str.indexOf('_')` within the test?

Comment: I owe you a huge apology, you are right, I did not read the link correctly, slice method provides more operations per second.

Comment: I appriciate it guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/DfxZEn/2), in order to match two capturing groups as you've defined.

Within context this would look like:

```
var match = (/^.*#(.*\/([.\w]+)$)/g).exec("8;#reports/125/ReportList/closedTasks.rdl");

// match[1] = "reports/125/ReportList/closedTasks.rdl"
// match[2] = "closedTasks.rdl"
```

Explanation:

- The first capturing group contains everything after a `#`
- The second capturing group (within the first one) contains all the alpha-numeric\dot characters after the last `/`.